# Maven how to start a server.jar in a pom.xml for integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, integration, embedded-tomcat-10

This question strikes me as being the same as [problem deploying project jar to running container that was started with maven cargo plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702179/problem-deploying-project-jar-to-running-container-that-was-started-with-maven-c). However the answer there is more than 12 years old. I want to see if there is a modern solution.

I have a multi-module Maven project with the structure

```
repo/pom.xml
  - server/pom.xml
  - integration/pom.xml
```

Originally the server we produced is a `war` file. In the integration module we have tests that target the server and validate it. To this end we use the `cargo-maven3-plugin` to start a tomcat container, deploy the `war` to Tomcat, and run the server on the `local host`.

Now we're refactoring the project to replace the `war` file with an embedded tomcat jar. i.e. Using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. In this new setup I want to persist the existing behaviour. Namely that maven launches the server and then runs the integration tests against the `local host`.

What is the best approach to achieving this? I've been experimenting with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but I'm getting weird errors with it. e.g.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/user/Development/project/integration/--spring.application.admin.enabled=true (No such file or directory)

Which approach is recommended here? Where can I find an example?

Comment: The question which comes to my mind. Why do you deploy a spring boot project via cargo into a container? Why not using the spring boot project itself .. it contains tomcat etc.. .? And to run integration tests is not a good idea to use Maven for that.. Better things like usual integration tests on Spring Boot side etc. Why do you really need tests via the container?

Comment: Originally the code was not spring boot. The server was packaged as a war, in the integration module we used cargo to launch Tomcat and deploy the war. I want to move away from this approach. We now use spring-boot and are switching the server to a jar. But I need to retain the existing integration module behaviour. i.e. Where it launches the server via Maven and executes the integration tests against it.

Comment: I strongly recommend to get rid of that old cargo launch setup ... Spring Boot itself has better support.. Why do you need to retain that? Technically you could launch a spring boot app via `spring-boot:run`? for integration testing but that's a bad idea... Check this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/fosdem2021 and more explanations here: https://archive.fosdem.org/2021/schedule/event/endtoendtests/

Comment: We're in a transition phase where we're moving from a war to embedded tomcat jar. This phase is expected to roll out slowly over a few months, during which we'll support both war (deployed to the cloud) and jar (dev work) builds. I don't have control over this process. But, as I have to have to support both, I'd like to keep the builds consistent. i.e.  The integration module launches the server and runs the tests against it. I was hitting problems with spring-boot:run, related to TestNG.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `io.soebes.simple.rest.application` plugin to launch the server in your E2E tests. When I got the `spring-boot:run` issue I was trying to place that into the integration module's pom.xml. This lead to the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: repo/my/server/--spring.application.admin.enabled=true (No such file or directory)`. Not sure what would cause that. I'm almost certainly trying to use the plugin incorrectly in my desire to replicate the cargo functionality. i.e. To launch the server directly, without an external tomcat.

Comment: BTW, in general I _thought_ that switching the cargo plugin with an alternative that just launches the jar file directly, would be the simplest solution. I've been so what surprised by how long it has taken and how undocumented it it. That's a sign that I may be too focused on this solution.

Comment: The question is really what kind of advance you have starting a spring boot application instead of using usual unit- and integration tests without starting up the whole application...Also you seemed to misunderstood the idea of the example because it does not use `spring-boot:run`... and also the output of the error shows some problems...

Comment: The tests are bundled as an executable jar file. To catch any build breaks before the deploy, on our build step we launch the server locally and run the integration tests against it. This means the tests run twice during a build. First against a local run of the server (to catch issues before a deploy), then against the integration env (to catch integration env configuration problems) after a deploy.